# Python: read multiple files from a location > create checksum values for each> store them in new files

Tags: python, checksum

I have this tiny project at work where I need to read 300 files from a location, create checksum values (md5) and store them in a new file(one new file for each checksum value). The contents of the new files should have col1: filename col2: Checksumvalue col2:

I have the code for creating checksums however unable to figure out how to be recursive(using for loop).
`

```
#I have so far is: 

with open ('filename','rb') as f:
            createchecksum =f.read()
            x = hasher.update(createchecksum)
            print (x)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need recursion for this unless the location of your files contains nested directories. Assuming that that is the case and you want a file containing the file names and their checksums, this is what you could do:

```
def generateChecksum(filename):
   with open (filename, 'rb') as f:
       createchecksum = f.read()
       return hasher.update(createchecksum)

def getChecksums(dir, results):
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.is_file():
                results[entry.path] = generateChecksum(entry.path)
            else:
                getChecksums(entry.path, results)

location = '' # Populate this with the location for your file
results = {}
getChecksums(location, results)

results_loc = '' # Populate this with the filename you want to write checksums to
with open(results_loc, 'w') as f:
    for file, checksum in results.items():
        f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))
```

This code works by going over all the entries in your directory and generating the checksum for each file in a depth-first search. It then writes the data to a results file.